# Problems (re)installing Ubuntu One 3.0.2 on Windows XP?

Tags: ubuntu-one-windows

I had previously installed an Ubuntu One client as a test on a Windows XP machine. Now I wanted to *change the account* for the client to a production one but had problems changing the email address so decided to do a reinstall.

- Ran uninstall.
- Downloaded `ubuntuone-3.0.2-windows-installer.exe`.
- It downloads, goes through the unpacking/install – strangely some of the messages say updating as if it was replacing something that was already there.
- I do not get the setup/signin screen. There is no `ubuntu%` processes running. The `Program files/ubuntuone` directory exists with data and dist folders.
- The U icon is on the desktop – pointing at `ubuntuone/dist/ubuntuone-control-panel-qt.exe` but this does not run.

Ran uninstall again, deleted `Program files/ubuntuone` directory, removed any ubuntu entries for registry, remove all 'application data' ubuntu files and directories, rebooted. Downloaded install again - exactly the same as above.

From the deleted registry entries the previous successful install was 2.0.3, I therefore re-installed 2.0.3 and everything is working again.
Not sure if this is a problem with this computer or a more general problem with 3.0.2 and XP?

Comment: what about `%appdata%` directory? look for any entry

Comment: @Web-E - thanks, have also tried deleting 'application data' files and directories - no difference.

Comment: @user73303 Could you test the workaround from the answer and indicate if worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Known bug with 3.0.2 windows installer.
https://launchpad.net/bugs/1017019

Workaround for the problem from the same article:

> Delete `mswsock.dll` and `powrprof.dll` from UbuntuOne
>   installation directory/dist subdirectory (e.g. `C:\Program
>   Files\ubuntuone\dist`). After this the native libraries will be used
>   and the application will be able to start.

The [reason](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-windows-installer/+bug/1017019/comments/4) is:

> `dist/mswsock.dll` and `dist/powrprof.dll` [...] were taken from
>   a Windows7 system